# Elastic Search: No query registered for [or]

Tags: ruby, elasticsearch

Can anyone help me with this query? I am getting an error returned: "No query registered for [or]" Did I structure this wrong? It's supposed to filter all results where area is 530 and start is blank OR area is 530 and start is "06192013", then based on that boost the document with the other filters.

```
{
  "query": {
    "custom_filters_score": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {"field":{"sector":"sector1"}},
            {"term":{"user_type":"ghost"}},
            {"term":{"area":"530"}}
          ]
        },
        "filter":{
          "or": [
            {
              "and": [
                {"term":{"area":"530"}},
                {"term":{"start":"06192013"}}
              ]
            },
            {
              "and": [
                {"term":{"area":"530"}},
                {"term":{"start":"blank"}}
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "filters": [
        {"filter":{"term":{"relevance" :5726}},"boost":"1000"},
        {"filter":{"term":{"relevance2":5726}},"boost":"100"}
      ],
      "score_mode":"total"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The filter object that contains the or filter is misplaced. I guess you wanted to use a [filtered query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/query-dsl/filtered-query/) containing the bool query and the or filter like this:

```
{
    "filtered" : {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {"field":{"sector":"sector1"}},
            {"term":{"user_type":"ghost"}},
            {"term":{"area":"530"}}
          ]
        },
        "filter" : {
            "or": [
            {
              "and": [
                {"term":{"area":"530"}},
                {"term":{"start":"06192013"}}
              ]
            },
            {
              "and": [
                {"term":{"area":"530"}},
                {"term":{"start":"blank"}}
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
    }
}
```